# How to set the user agent for all links including ios swift redirects?

Tags: ios, swift, webview

Please tell me how can I set the user agent for all links, including ios swift redirects?

As you can see in the screenshot below, for some reason the user agent of the device still skips, but another one should be installed.

[image]

```
import UIKit
import WebKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, WKNavigationDelegate, WKUIDelegate {
    
    var webView: WKWebView!
    let userAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/17.3.1 Safari/605.1.15"
    
    override func loadView() {
        let webConfiguration = WKWebViewConfiguration()
        webView = WKWebView(frame: .zero, configuration: webConfiguration)
        webView.uiDelegate = self
        webView.navigationDelegate = self
        view = webView
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let myURL = URL(string: "https://test.com/")
        let myRequest = URLRequest(url: myURL!)
        webView.customUserAgent = userAgent
        webView.load(myRequest)
    }
    
    func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, decidePolicyFor navigationAction: WKNavigationAction, decisionHandler: @escaping (WKNavigationActionPolicy) -> Void) {
        var request = navigationAction.request
        webView.customUserAgent = userAgent
        print(navigationAction.request.value(forHTTPHeaderField: "User-Agent"))
        decisionHandler(.allow)
    }
}
```